# How to set min/max interval and values for jQuery UI slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I jave a problem with jQuery UI Slider.

I have a function "Pricer()" and arguments that I give to it:

1)min_price, max_price - interval range ( min_price-------------max_price )

2)start_price, end_price - subinterval ( min price----start_price--------end_price-----max_price )

Code:

```
function Pricer(min_price, max_price, start_price, end_price) {
    $( "#slider_price" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: min_price,
        step:10,
        max: max_price,
        values: [start_price,  end_price ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#price1').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#price2').val(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });

    $('#price1').change(function () {
        $('#slider_price').slider("values",0, $(this).val());
    });

    $('#price2').change( function() {
        $('#slider_price').slider("values",1,$(this).val());
    });

    $('#price1').val($('#slider_price').slider("values",0));
    $('#price2').val($('#slider_price').slider("values",1));
};
```

I call this function twice in order:

1) on document.ready event. ( Pricer(4, 536, 4, 536); )

2) when I should set new values to slider. ( Pricer(4, 536, 11, 12) )

And get the wrong interval:

```
$('#slider_price').slider('values', 0)
```

and

```
$('#slider_price').slider('values', 1)
```

returns to me value '14' and '14'.

I debug it and found that it happend when I set values property in object which I send to slider().

I didn't found open bug reports in jQuery UI slider. May be it is my misunderstanding of jQuery UI slider work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that you set the `step` to 10. Since your range starts with 4 the next closest value to 11 and 12 is 14.

[Slider Widget API doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step) about step states that:

*(Step) Determines the size or amount of each interval or step the slider takes between the min and max. The full specified value range of the slider (max - min) should be evenly divisible by the step.*

Comment: WOW, Thanks, I don't thought about it)